# EmguCV not reading camera

Tags: c#, emgucv

I have the the following code in a normal windows form application with EmguCV 3.1

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _capture = new Capture("http://root:pass@192.168.1.27:80/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi");
        _capture.ImageGrabbed += ProcessFrame;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _capture.Start();
    }

    private void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Mat image = new Mat();
        _capture.Retrieve(image);
        imageBox1.BackgroundImage = image.Bitmap;

    }
```

I have tested the above link in a browser it worked, I have also tested this using iSpy it also works there but using EmguCV ProcessFrame is never reached

I have also tried to connect to the camera using Luxand and it worked well but Luxand is not free so I have to use EmguCV to do face detection & recognition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at this [post](http://answers.opencv.org/question/17210/d-link-ip-cam-read-stream-and-picture/), try adding ?x.mjpeg after .cgi in your url.