# Cannot use Emgu CV to connect to a local IP camera

Tags: c#, emgucv

I have an IP camera connected through a POE switch and I'm able to log into the camera web page and view the live stream. I'm trying to capture the video stream in my *.Net Winforms* application using `Emgu CV 3.2` and nothing I've tried is working.

Here are all the variations I've tried:

```
m_capture = new VideoCapture("rtsp://admin:123456@192.168.0.123");
if (!m_capture.IsOpened) m_capture = new VideoCapture("rtsp://admin:123456@192.168.0.123:554");
if (!m_capture.IsOpened) m_capture = new VideoCapture("http://admin:123456@192.168.0.123");
if (!m_capture.IsOpened) m_capture = new VideoCapture("http://admin:123456@192.168.0.123:80");
```

Looking at the video capture constructor though, it seems like it's interpreting the constructor URL as a file path... What am I doing wrong?

```
 public VideoCapture(String fileName)
 {
      using (CvString s = new CvString(fileName))
      {
      /*
      if (Util.CvToolbox.HasFFMPEG)
      {
           _captureModuleType = CaptureModuleType.FFMPEG;
           _ptr = CvInvoke.cvCreateFileCapture_FFMPEG(fileName);
      }
      else*/
      {
           _captureModuleType = CaptureModuleType.Highgui;
           _ptr = CvInvoke.cveVideoCaptureCreateFromFile(s);
      }

      if (_ptr == IntPtr.Zero)
           throw new NullReferenceException(String.Format("Unable to create capture from {0}", fileName));
 }
```

Comment: I've done a little digging on this following `CvInvoke.cveVideoCaptureCreateFromFile(s);`. Ultimately this points to the OpenCV (C++) constructor here: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/videoio/src/cap.cpp. It won't be much help to you but it seems, to me at least, as this function does not support URL streams despite what it says.

Comment: Maybe this is related to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40772274/emgucv-not-reading-camera ?